# strcmp and wcscmp

Tags: c, strcmp

Is this

```
if( (FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) &&
    (wcscmp(FileData.cFileName, L".") != 0) &&
    (wcscmp(FileData.cFileName, L"..") != 0) )
```

the same as this:

```
if( (FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) &&
    wcscmp(FileData.cFileName, L".") &&
    wcscmp(FileData.cFileName, L"..") )
```

And also if you use `strcmp` instead of `wcscmp`? It should check equality (strict) of the name with ".." and "." (directory search).

Thanks!

Comment: I can't spot any other difference than the missing parantheses in your second example - am I blind or did you forget something? EDIT: Ah, now I see it.

Comment: the `!=0` are also omitted :)

Comment: @rubenb: Then the question isn't about wcscmp, it's about `if` statements. There's nothing about wcscmp that makes it special; it's just a function that returns an int.

Comment: @Billy: MSDN states it can return a lot more values than 0 and 1, I was just making sure I didn't miss any corner cases.

Comment: That's what made me wonder - `wcscmp()` is just `strcmp()` for widestrings and returns the same :)

Comment: @rubenvb The other return codes just tell you where a difference was found. If `wscmp()` returns "4", there's a difference at position 4.

Comment: @lukeN: OK, but MSDN seems to say it compares precedence lexicographically, and C locale-dependent. But if 0 is only returned when I expect, then that's great and I can forget about this piece of nasty C-stuff :)

Comment: @rubenvb I once learned that `...cmp()` always returns 0 on a complete string match without differences and it never failed me so far :)

Comment: @LukeN: According to the C99 standard: "The wcscmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero,
accordingly as the wide string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the
wide string pointed to by s2."  If `wcscmp()` returns 4, all it means is that the first string is greater than the second.

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, but the two forms are the same code. If there was a problem with values other than 1 or 0, they would be the same problems between the two samples. C boolean expressions are inherently `!= 0` expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, both examples do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

In C, "true" is defined as "not zero".  "false" is defined as "zero".  So yes, they're the same.

Do be careful about methods that return non-primitive types, though; in C++, operator overloading could make "!= 0" not actually compare something with zero :-P.  Not a problem here, though.

Also, if you don't put in the parentheses, make sure you understand the order of operations.